# Chrome app, open link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome app, which will simply open a link, for example "http://www.cnn.com/" in a new tab in chrome.

I have the following code in my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CNN",
  "version": "2.1",
  "permissions": ["webview", "pointerLock", "geolocation", "videoCapture"],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what i have in main.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('http://www.cnn.com/', {

  });
});
```

I have also tried,

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create({ "url": "http://cloudsupport.neonova.net/home" });
});
```

as well as:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.app.tab.create({ "url": "http://cloudsupport.neonova.net/home" });
});
```

PLease help.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you building an app for just opening link?

Comment: you want page to open whenever chrome opens up?

Comment: where is tab permission? shouldn't you have it

Comment: ALso what is happening when you run this code

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I want the page to open when I launch the app. I added the tab permission. When I double click on the app from Chrome:Apps , the page that is open "Chrome:Apps" closes and that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyway, I've tried `window.open` and it forked like a charm:

```
'use strict';

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    window.open("https://google.com/");
});
```

So it might work for you as well.

Comment: What does 'use strict'; do?

Comment: @user3464774 It turns on ECMAScript's Strict Mode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1335881/1593459

Comment: wont this open a new window instead of tab

Comment: use strict guarantees that in future your code will stop working. :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It shouldn't. It is counter-intuitive, but that's how things work. It's a tradition going back to ~2004, when tabs in browsers were a new cool feature®.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer in fact there is an option in Firefox to make `window.open` open real new windows, but haven't seen one in Chrome.

Comment: this opens popup in chrome

Answer (score 6):

As of chrome 42, [chrome.browser](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser) may help:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.browser.openTab({
      url: 'https://google.com/'
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

**Reference:** https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

```
var options= { url: "http://cloudsupport.neonova.net/home" };

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.create(options);
});
```

then in manifest.json. add this permission.

```
...
"permissions": ["tabs","webview", "pointerLock", "geolocation", "videoCapture"]
...
```

Comment: Seems like more native way to do it, but why would you need all these permissions (especially `geolocation` and `videoCapture`)?

Comment: i don't know that's what op has...for this you only need tabs permission because you are accessing url...Though i am not sure if you need any permission. But just in case if it's needed i'll wont hesitate to add tabs permission. there is one more permission type called activeTab

Comment: And i am not sure what will happen if no chrome instance is running. Ill have to check, what happens if no windows is open...there can't be a tab if there is no window. maybe code should check that if window is open or not. Or maybe tabs.create itself opens a window if there isn't one open already..

Comment: Note that chrome.tabs.create will only work in extensions or legacy packaged apps.